# What is the relation between $Irr(a, F)$ and $Irr(a, K)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

We have that $F \leq K \leq L$ and $a \in L$.
If $a$ is algebraic over $F$ then it is also algebraic over $K$.
What is the relation between $Irr(a, F)$ and $Irr(a, K)$?

Let $Irr(a, K)=p(x) \in K[x]$ and $Irr(a, F)=q(x) \in F[x]$.
Then $q(x) \in F[x] \subseteq K[x]$ with $q(a)=0$

How can I continue?

Comment: Hint: since $q(a)=0$ then $p$ divides $q$.

Comment: @egreg Why does this stand??

Comment: Write $q(x)=p(x)s(x)+r(x)$ where the degree of $r$ is less than the degree of $p$ (you know you can, don't you?). Since $q(a)=0$, we have $0=p(a)s(a)+r(a)$ and so $r(a)=0$. Thus…

Comment: So, this means that $deg r(x) \leq deg p(x)$. Since $r(a)=0$ it follows that $r(x)=Irr(a, K)$. That is a contradiction, right??

Comment: Yes, unless $r$ is the zero polynomial.

Comment: @egreg Ok!! Thanks a lot!! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints

1. If $p=\operatorname{Irr}(a,K)$ is the minimal polynomial for $a$ over $K$ and if $q\in K[x]$ has the property that $q(a)=0$, then $p$ divides $q$ (remember that $K[x]$ is a principal ideal domain and the characterization of the minimal polynomial).
2. If $q=\operatorname{Irr}(a,F)$, then $q\in K[x]$ and $q(a)=0$.
3. So…

Comment: what does irr(a,K) stands for?

Comment: @HungerLearn Somebody uses this notation for the monic minimal polynomial of $a$ over $K$. I don't usually employ it, but it was in the OP's question.